# How to scroll down an element in Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I have a leader board element that I need to scroll down to view all players at the top of a web page using Selenium Java.  Having spent the past 2 hrs googling I am only able to find answers by scrolling down a page that is not what I need.

I Have tried the following

```
        //click on leaderboard
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div")).click();

    //scroll
    WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"accordion-panel-1720\"]/div[2]/div"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(scroll).perform();
```

and

```
        WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"accordion-panel-1720\"]/div[2]/div"));
    Actions act = new Actions(scroll);
    act.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).build().perform(); //Page Down
    System.out.println("Scroll down perfomed");
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, I've found two ways to do this for me:
using Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.PAGE_DOWN
or executing a Javascript to scroll the element up/down.

```java
JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExec.executeScript("document.getElementById('id').scrollTop += 100");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript executor

For scroll down,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
```

For scroll Up,

```
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
```

you can also use to scroll until element is visible

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

You can refer to [this site](https://www.guru99.com/scroll-up-down-selenium-webdriver.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).